# Error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python

I've some error in my coding

```
ki = raw_input("Enter Initial Key in HEX 20 bit :") 
IV = raw_input("Enter Initial vector in HEX 16 bit :")

for i in xrange(0,20,2):
if(ki[i]>='0' and ki[i]<='9'):
    ie=ki[i]-'0'
elif (ki[i]>='a' and ki[i]<='f'):
    ie=ki[i]-'a'+10
elif (ki[i]>='A' and ki[i]<='F'):
    ie=ki[i]-'A'+10
```

This error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/MrX/PycharmProjects/grain/grain.py", line 16, in 
>   ie=ki[i]-'0'; TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and
>   'str'

I hope you can help me to fix it. Thanks

Comment: What's your code supposed to do?

Comment: You can not subtract a string from a string even if there are numbers inside.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `-` operand on a string:

```
ie = ki[i] - 'a' + 10
```

I presume you thought simple quotes in Python referred to the character's ASCII value. However, in Python, simple quotes and double quotes are strictly equivalent, and they both represent strings.

What you want is the `ord` function:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
```